# Preseed /dev/shm

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, preseed

I'm able to create all partitions besides /dev/shm. I assume it requires a special configuration like swap, but I don't know where to find that information.

Here's what I have, but it fails at debian-installer.

```
        1024 4000 1088 ext4 $lvmok{ }                         \
        mountpoint{ /dev/shm }                                \
        lv_name{ devshm  }                                    \
        in_vg { ubuntu }                                      \
        method{ format }                                      \
        format{ }                                             \
        use_filesystem{ }                                     \
        filesystem{ ext4 }                                    \
        options/nosuid{ nosuid }                              \
        options/nodev{ nodev }                                \
        options/noexec{ noexec }                              \
        .                                                     \
```

`mount | grep /dev/shm` should return something like this this:

`tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file system is the issue here.

Change `ext4` to `tmpfs`.

```
        1024 4000 1088 ext4 $lvmok{ }                         \
        mountpoint{ /dev/shm }                                \
        lv_name{ dev-shm  }                                   \
        in_vg { ubuntu }                                      \
        method{ format }                                      \
        format{ }                                             \
        use_filesystem{ }                                     \
        filesystem{ tmpfs }                                   \
        options/nosuid{ nosuid }                              \
        options/nodev{ nodev }                                \
        options/noexec{ noexec }                              \
        .                                                     \
```